# Регулярка для поиска и замены знака

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Амперсанд встречается отбитый пробелами `бла-бла & бла` и в словах `бла&, бла&бла, &бла`. В самом первом случае нужно его менять на `et`, а в остальных случаях на `&amp;` Я нашла ресурс, где можно тестить эти самые регулярки, но нифига не получается. Пробовала вот так `\s&\s`, но съедаются пробелы (в первом случае), а для остальных вообще не работает :( Мне для `preg_replace('/регулярка/', '&amp;', $text)` и так далее.

Comment: Попробуйте позитивный просмотр назад и вперед `(?<=\s)&(?=\s)` для замены знака ограниченного пробельными символами, а следующей заменой заменяйте все остальные символы

Comment: мб чтобы пробелы в первом случае не съедались, надо в строке замены тоже их оставить?

Comment: @teran надо тогда их в группу брать и группой возвращать, так как `\s` может быть и табуляцией и переводом строки и т.д.

Comment: не пробовали просто заменять не на 'et', а на ' et '? Думаю самым простым решением будет.

Comment: `preg_replace(['/&/', '/(\s)et(\s)/',], ['et', '$1&amp;$1'], $text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так (обратите внимание на пробелы в строках, на которые заменяется выражение):
`preg_replace(['/\s&\s/', '/([^\s])&\s/', '/([^\s])&([^\s])/', '/\s&([^\s])/'], [' et ', '$1&amp; ', '$1&amp;$2', ' &amp;$1'], $text)`

Comment: Я не гуру и, скорее всего, мой ответ не будет идеальным и потребует доработки. Но работать должен)